# How to produce verified squashed commits on GitLab?

Tags: git, authentication, security, gitlab

We use **auto-squashing** in **GitLab** merge requests to get a nice git history. We also use git commit signing to get **verified commits**. But when GitLab actually squashes on merge, it creates an unsigned commit on our main branch. Our current workaround is to squash locally before creating the merge request. But with every change required during review, this workaround gets more and more annoying. How do you solve this problem professionally?

Comment: how can you trust a signed commit if the signing key is on a server?

Comment: isn't it better to squash commits locally so that you can keep the msg according to the changes you have done.

Comment: Regarding trust issues with GitLab: It has full access to all my code. I build my products based on code managed by GitLab. Yes, I trust my GitLab server. However, I do not trust an author tag on an unverified commit.

Comment: Local squashing: This makes the workflow uncomfortable. I want to use GitLab's "protected branch workflow". Ideally, the reviewer accepts the merge request and can merge directly. With local squashing, either the reviewer or the committer has to reopen the project, squash and push. And after that final squash push, you would also have a dirty branch again, and the other person would have to check that the squasher did not screw things up.

Comment: Commit message on auto-squashing: GitLab allows you to edit the message on auto-squashing. In my opinion, this is a non-existent problem.

Comment: There could be a way. Maybe you can teach GL to only accept a push (protected) if the change that it would introduce is equal to an accepted MR. So could maybe solve indirectly. However, solving it directly seems hard. You want to GPG sign your commits. But you want GL to do the (squash) commit. Giving GL the ability to sign your commits would be the same as giving your GPG identity away.

Comment: I don't want to give GitLab my signing credentials. I'd like GitLab to use its own credentials. The main goal here would be to only allow verified commits.

Comment: I agree with Martin. Give GitLab its own signature for its squashes.

Comment: Further to that, the GitLab signature needs to be used by GitLab just for merges/squashes, not regular gitlab UI commits. That way you know that all code included in those squashed commits has already been signed and verified against real authors in those previous commits.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the professional answer to my question from Linus Torvalds: "Dont do it. Be happy with 'git tag -s'. It really is the right way."

In April 2009 he wrote a text on this topic. You can still find it online here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210415082241/https://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/GPG-signing-for-git-commit-td2582986.html

In practice, it is pointless to sign each commit since many operations would invalidate those signatures. Only Git tags need to be signed.